# Multiple CordovaWebViews in one Android activity?

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

CordovaWebView was introduced in cordova 1.9. 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html

Anyone tried putting multiple webviews in one activity? will it work? is it recommended?

Answer (score 0):

It is doable. The cordova guide does provide some hint.

Also assume MyActivity extends DriodGap then need to

1) override the `init()` method

2) change the dimension of the first (original view) so that it doesn't take the whole screen

```
this.appView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    [desired width],
    [desired height],
));
```

3) Create a new CordovaWebView, set its LayoutParams similar to the first one. Then add it to the root view:

```
this.root.addView(cwv2);
```

4) The two web views should show up now. But if there are Inputs in the two views you will find that there is focus in both inputs.

5) To get rid of the double focus issue insert the following code:

```
this.appView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
this.appView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                       v.requestFocus();
                   }
                   break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```